# In 2.8 how can I return the 3D cursor settings back into the Item tab?

Tags: interface

Prior to 2.8, the context menu (N) showed both the current selection properties and the 3D cursor properties, which I found very useful. Now I have to constantly mouse up and switch the tabs, and it's frustrating me.

It doesn't seem like I can drag it to the Item tab. Is there any way to return to the old layout, just for this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Additional 3d Cursor Panel",
    "author": "Martynas Žiemys",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "n panel, Item tab",
    "description": "Adds 3d Cursor properties to Item tab",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "UI",
}

import bpy 

from bpy.types import Panel

class VIEW3D_PT_view3d_additional_cursor(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Item"
    bl_label = "3D Cursor"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        cursor = context.scene.cursor

        layout.column().prop(cursor, "location", text="Location")
        rotation_mode = cursor.rotation_mode
        if rotation_mode == 'QUATERNION':
            layout.column().prop(cursor, "rotation_quaternion", text="Rotation")
        elif rotation_mode == 'AXIS_ANGLE':
            layout.column().prop(cursor, "rotation_axis_angle", text="Rotation")
        else:
            layout.column().prop(cursor, "rotation_euler", text="Rotation")
        layout.prop(cursor, "rotation_mode", text="")

def register():  
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_view3d_additional_cursor)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_view3d_additional_cursor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you copy and paste that into the Text editor and then save it to a file with a .py extension, you can then install this as an add-on, that adds the functionality:

[image]

Comment: I'll try this. So if future UI changes make it so that this start throwing errors, would I be able to disable this "addon" like any other?

Comment: [Sure, it's formed as any other add-on.](https://i.imgur.com/xWupL9b.gif) It is a simple add-on.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for knocking this out. I am having trouble finding it after installing though. Searching for the name (or partially) doesn't show any results, and it doesn't appear to be working in the interface. There was a little blurb about one or more addons not being UTF-8. I made sure the file I created was UTF-8 encoded, so not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Nevermind! I didn't save the encoding change lol. Works like a charm now.

Comment: That's why I meant to recommend to copy it to Blender's Text editor - it saves as UTF-8 by default as far as I know. Anyway, glad it works now.

Comment: Sticking to a standard Z over Ž will alleviate that happening.

Comment: I like my surname as it is. Luckily, UTF-8 encoding is perfectly suitable to encode it without mistakes and as far as I know, Blender uses UTF-8 for pretty much everything. I am even able to enjoy variable names containing all of my favourite letters such as ą, č, ę, ė, į, š, ų, ū and ž in my scripts. :)